# How's the ODE is turned to this auxiliary equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, factoring

I have the following ODE

$$ r\frac{d^{2}u}{dr^{2}} + 2\frac{du}{dr} = 0$$

i.e. $ru''+2u'=0$.

How is the ODE converted to this form of auxiliary equation:
$m(m-1)+2m=0$

I have no idea on how to proceed. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE, SNHF. You might want to learn how to format your equations using MathJax if you're planning on using this website more than once.

Comment: Use the ansatz $u(r) = r^m$

Answer (score 1):

To solve $ru'' + 2u'= 0$ apply the change of function
$$u(r)=r^m $$
so that
$$u'(r)=mr^{m-1}, ~~u''(r)=m(m-1)r^{m-2}$$
in order to obtain 
$$rm(m-1)r^{m-2}+2mr^{m-1}=0$$
which simplifies to
$$r^{m-1}\Big(m(m-1)+2m\Big)=0$$
where the auxillary equation is
$$m(m-1)+2m=0$$

Answer (score 1):

This is an Euler-Cauchy DE, where the standard solution method is to try to find solutions of the power type. In many cases this gives a full set of basis solutions. In your case where $m=0,-1$ these basis solutions are $u_1(r)=1$ and $u_2(r)=r^{-1}$. Any other solution is a linear combination.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Here it is another way to solve it. Multiply both sides by $r$ in order to obtain
\begin{align*}
ru^{\prime\prime} + 2u^{\prime} = 0 \Longleftrightarrow r^{2}u^{\prime\prime} + 2ru^{\prime} = 0 \Longleftrightarrow (r^{2}u^{\prime})^{\prime} = 0
\end{align*}

Comment: You could also recognize directly the Leibniz second order product derivative, $(ru)''=0$.